# Wrapper function which returns promise irrespective of function arguments

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

In my project, I have a scenario where I have different kind of functions with different arguments. One of those arguments holds the callback function. And also there is a case where the function doesn't have any arguments. As shown below:

```
abc(string, function, number)
aaa(function, string)
bcd()
xyz(function)
cda(string, number, function, string)
```

I need to write a function such that irrespective of the irregularity of above functions, the function should return a promise.

Example:

```
// Assume $q has been injected
var defer = $q.defer();
function returnPromise(functionName, functionArgumentsInArray){
    defer.resolve(window[functionName].apply(null, functionArgumentsInArray));
    return defer.promise;
}
```

As you can see, the above function doesn't resolve the callback function but just the function.

Note: The functions will have max of one function argument or none.

I know it can be done individually for each case as follows:

```
function returnPromise(){
    var defer = $q.defer();
    abc("hey", function() {
        defer.resolve(arguments);
    }, 123);
    return defer.promise;
}
```

But I am looking for a common wrapper for all such functions.

Comment: If it is not possible to know which (or whether any) of the parameters takes the callback, it also is impossible to write a generic wrapper.

Comment: @Bergi I have a slight idea to do something with arguments and typeof to check for function type. but don't know what to do next.

Comment: There are no arguments yet when you're just wrapping the function, and when the wrapper is called the callback will be omitted - and you have no chance to know in which position it belongs if any.

Comment: Btw, the function that doesn't take an argument (an no callback therefore), why would you want to wrap that in a promise-returning function at all?

Comment: @Bergi I am doing something like `returnPromise().then` later..

Comment: @Bergi `There are no arguments yet when you're just wrapping the function` - I am passing the arguments in the wrapper function. Please check first example. I think I need to replace the callback function somehow maybe using splice.

Comment: But when the wrapped function is returning a promise, you would not want to pass in a callback that one could replace?

Comment: @Bergi Yeah I think that is fine. or I will just pass something like null to then replace it with a function. because in that function I am just resolving the arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like

```
const cbPlaceholder = Symbol("placeholder for node callback");
function wrap(fn) {
    return function(...args) {
        return $q((resolve, reject) => {
            function nodeback(err, result) {
                if (err) reject(err);
                else resolve(result);
            }
            for (var i=0; i<args.length; i++)
                if (args[i] === cbPlaceholder) {
                    args[i] = nodeback;
                    break;
                }
            const res = fn.apply(this, args);
            if (i == args.length) // not found
                resolve(res);
        });
    };
}
```

You could use it as

```
const abcPromised = wrap(abc);
abcPromised("hey", cbPlaceholder, 123).then(…)
```

Also have a look at [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572). In general you should not need that placeholder thing when all promisified functions follow the convention to take the callback as their last parameter.

Comment: Thanks. I will accept once I understand the code :)